# Salesforce Rest Request, insert data

Tags: objective-c, salesforce

I'm using the salesforce iphonesdk, I wonder if anybody knows how to submit data into the salesforce object, like using INSERT ? Which method is to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With guidance by Lacey Snr,
Found my own answer

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic setObject:@"Smith" forKey:@"Name_c"];
[dic setObject:@"5" forKey:@"PAX_c"];
SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] 
                          requestForCreateWithObjectType:@"Booking_Forms_c" fields:dic];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `create()` call, passing it an array of `SObjects` to insert — [see the documentation here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_create.htm).

You should probably read the Getting Started section of the reference material, especially the [API Call Basics](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/calls.htm). Your question demonstrates a considerable lack of research, and I'd advise making sure you do research things yourself before asking a question on stackoverflow if you don't want it to be closed out. If you've read the documentation and still don't understand how to do something, then you're in a good position to ask for help!

Answer (score 1):

**Swift** version:

1. Your controller class should conform to `RestClientDelegate` protocol
2. `data` is the dictionary(object) to be inserted

```
let data = ["Percentage__c": "1", "Amount__c":"11", "Volume__c":"111", "Promotion_Details__c": "00112233"]
let request = RestClient.shared.requestForCreate(withObjectType: "<your_table_name_>", fields: data)

RestClient.shared.send(request, delegate: self)
```

**Another Way:**

If you don't want to conform to `RestClientDelegate`, simply call:

```
RestClient.shared.send(request: request, onFailure: { (err, res) in
            // some closure to handle error
        }) { (any, res) in
            // another closure to handle error
        }
```